# What does this symbol ?: mean in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax

When the shorthand syntax used in the scenario, I'm trying to use it but its giving me some weird results

```
($value == 'yes' ?: 'Show Text');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the [binary conditional operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) introduced in PHP 5.3. PHP's conditional operator is traditionally a *ternary* operator (accepting three operands), but the binary (accepting two operands) form was added, making the operand between the `?` and `:` optional:

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns `expr1` if `expr1` evaluates to `TRUE`, and `expr3` otherwise.

So in your example, if `$value` is `'yes'`, the result is TRUE (1) because the result is the first expression's value (`$value == 'yes'`). If `$value` is not `'yes'`, the result is `'Show Text'`.

Comment: Also known as the elvis operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator

Comment: @SamDufel: Ah! And "doh" on the article, of course, in this form the conditional operator *isn't* a ternary operator, it's a binary operator. Cool.